# How can I convert Python boolean object to C int (or C++ boolean) (Python C API)

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I have a variable `PyObject` that I know is a Python bool. It either is `True` or `False` (eg. `Py_True` or `Py_False`). Now I would like to convert it to C++ somehow.

Doing this with strings isn't so hard, there is a helper function for that - `PyBytes_AsString` that converts python string into C string. Now I need something like that for boolean (or int as there is no `bool` in C).

Or if there isn't conversion, maybe some function that can compare with true or false? Something like `int PyBool_IsTrue(PyObject*)`?

Here is some example code for easier understanding of what I need:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    /* here I create Python boolean with value of True */
    PyObject *b = Py_RETURN_TRUE;
    /* now that I have it I would like to turn in into C type so that I can determine if it's True or False */
    /* something like */
    if (PyBool_IsTrue(b))
    { /* it's true! */ }
    else
    { /* it's false */ }
    return 0;
}
```

This obviously wouldn't work as there is no such function like `PyBool_IsTrue` :( how can I do that?

Snippet of Python header (boolobject.h):

```
/* Boolean object interface */

#ifndef Py_BOOLOBJECT_H
#define Py_BOOLOBJECT_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) PyBool_Type;

#define PyBool_Check(x) (Py_TYPE(x) == &PyBool_Type)

/* Py_False and Py_True are the only two bools in existence.
Don't forget to apply Py_INCREF() when returning either!!! */

/* Don't use these directly */
PyAPI_DATA(struct _longobject) _Py_FalseStruct, _Py_TrueStruct;

/* Use these macros */
#define Py_False ((PyObject *) &_Py_FalseStruct)
#define Py_True ((PyObject *) &_Py_TrueStruct)

/* Macros for returning Py_True or Py_False, respectively */
#define Py_RETURN_TRUE return Py_INCREF(Py_True), Py_True
#define Py_RETURN_FALSE return Py_INCREF(Py_False), Py_False

/* Function to return a bool from a C long */
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyBool_FromLong(long);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* !Py_BOOLOBJECT_H */
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Every* Python object can have its truthiness evaluated with [`PyObject_IsTrue`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsTrue), and you should use this in preference to direct `PyTrue`/`PyFalse` singleton checking unless you absolutely know, for certain, that the object is a `PyBool`.

Usage is:

```
int truthy = PyObject_IsTrue(someobj);
if (truthy == -1) return APPROPRIATEERRORRETURN;

if (truthy)
{ /* it's true! */ }
else
{ /* it's false */ }
```

You can just test `someobj == Py_True` if you know it's definitely a bool, or use [`PyNumber_AsSsize_t`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_AsSsize_t) to convert any logical integer type (anything implementing `__index__`, and `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so it's also logically an integer) to a signed `size_t` value (if `__index__` returns a number that doesn't fit in signed `size_t`, it will return -1 with exception set).

The reason not to do `someobj == Py_True` in general is because it's like doing `if someobj is True:` at the Python layer. If `someobj` is `1`, or an non-empty `str`, that will treat it as false, when Pythonic code is rarely concerned about being `True` or `False`, but rather, "truthiness" and "falsiness".

In addition, this:

```
PyObject *b = Py_RETURN_TRUE;
```

is flat wrong. That will incref `PyTrue` and return it; none of the subsequent code will execute. You'd want:

```
PyObject *b = Py_True;
```

for a borrowed reference, adding a subsequent:

```
Py_INCREF(b);
```

to make it an owned reference if you intended to return it later (since it's a singleton that won't go away, using a borrowed reference is fine unless you know it will be `DECREF`ed later, e.g. because you returned it and passed ownership to a caller who can't know it's a borrowed reference).

Comment: Will `PyObject *b = Py_RETURN_TRUE;` even compile?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Probably not, but I put nothing past a compiler running with warnings off in non-strict mode. :-)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in Python headers but may not be obvious.

Python headers declare 2 somewhat static objects here, with couple of macros:

```
/* Don't use these directly */
PyAPI_DATA(struct _longobject) _Py_FalseStruct, _Py_TrueStruct;

/* Use these macros */
#define Py_False ((PyObject *) &_Py_FalseStruct)
#define Py_True ((PyObject *) &_Py_TrueStruct)

/* Macros for returning Py_True or Py_False, respectively */
#define Py_RETURN_TRUE return Py_INCREF(Py_True), Py_True
#define Py_RETURN_FALSE return Py_INCREF(Py_False), Py_False
```

It seems that both `True` and `False` are in fact Python objects and all values in Python that are `True` or `False` are in fact references to these two global `Py_True` and `Py_False` objects. When such object is returned using `Py_RETURN_TRUE`, the reference count is incremented.

This means that every C pointer that points to PyObject of value `Py_True` in fact points to same memory address. Therefore checking if `PyObject` is true or false is as simple as:

```
/* here I create Python boolean with value of True */
PyObject *b = Py_True;
Py_INCREF(b);
/* now we compare the address of pointer with address of Py_True */
if (b == Py_True)
{ /* it's true! */ }
else
{ /* it's false */ }
```

It's generally good idea to use `int PyBool_Check(PyObject*)` to verify if object in question is Python boolean.

Comment: Not very good advice, and doesn't address some major issues in OP's approach.